# Is there a current version of Ubuntu that works on a laptop with an nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

Is there a current version of Ubuntu or a linux kernel beyond 5.8 that works with an nvidia graphics driver. I currently have an installation of Ubuntu 20.4 LTS, but I have to manually load Linux kernel 5.8 because none of the newer kernels will load the Nvidia graphics driver on boot. All I get is a black screen with a randomly blinking cursor. I also tried a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.4.3 on a new hard drive and although the installation completed successfully and graphics were working, when the system rebooted, once again I was left with a black screen with a randomly blinking cursor. Is there a current version of Ubuntu that doesn't have this problem with the Nvidia driver?

Comment: Would Ubuntu 21.10 work for you? It is newer, so it might work better. If it's still giving you trouble, consider a different distro. [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/), for example, handles the NVIDIA drivers by default, so it might just work. I've also used [Zorin OS](https://zorin.com/os/) which also can automatically set up the NVIDIA drivers. Of course, both of those distros are off-topic here (they are not official derivatives), but consider them if you aren't too attached to Ubuntu. They are based on Ubuntu/Debian, so they should be mostly familiar.

Comment: It depends on the version of the driver. Is it nouveau or nvidia? Which version?

Comment: Is Ubuntu 21.10 still in Beta or have they officially released it? Has anyone experienced problems with 21.10 and the Nvidia driver? When I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 just a few days ago, I installed in on a new hard drive,, but I never imported any of my other data from the previous version of Ubuntu, so I am ready to just wipe the failed version of 20.04.3 and replace it with whatever version of Ubuntu that doesn't have a problem with Nvidia. When I installed 20.04.3, I used the option to install the propietary driver for Nvidia following the installation.